# Getting a value from another form's combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I can't get value from form2 combobox. I checked that combobox modifier set to 'Public'.

I get the 'Object not referenced to instance of a object' error. What is the mistake?

```
//Form1
private DialogIO dio;

private void uosIO_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dio = new DialogIO();
   dio.Show(); // Open Form2 and Set Some value on Combobox
}


// BGWorker get run call from form2 and run it on form1.
private void bgwCustomIO_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(dio.uceMinHour.Text); // Show Combobox Value
}
```

Comment: @RenéVogt edited question.BG Worker runs on form1 but form2 triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

consider check for null also...

```
 private void bgwCustomIO_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dio == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dio.uceMinHour.Text))
        {
            return;
        }
       MessageBox.Show(dio.uceMinHour.Text); // Show Combobox Value
    }
```

Comment: remove this. it is not null at all.

Comment: which part dio or the text?

Comment: oh god. just remove this answer.

Comment: I mean which part cannot be null the instance of dio or the Text property?